# How to deserialize foreignkey with django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKeyField(People)
    content = models.TextField()
```

and then，

```
class CreateBlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    #author id
    author = serializers.IntegerField()
    content = serializers.TextField()
```

In views, I need to get author_id , check if the id exists and get the author instance, it's fussy to do that.

```
serializer = CreateBlogSerializer(data=request.DATA)
if serializer.is_valid():
    try:
        author = Author.objects.get(pk=serializer.data["author"])
    except Author.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(data={"author does not exist"})
    blog = Blog.objects.create(author=author, content=serializer.data["content"])
```

Is there a ForeignKeyField to deserialize and validate primarykey data and then return a instance.

```
class CreateBlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    author = serializers.ForeignKeyField(Author)
    content = serializers.TextField()

serializer = CreateBlogSerializer(data=request.DATA)
if serializer.is_valid():
    #after deserialization , the author id becomes author model instance
    blog = Blog.objects.create(author=serializer.data["author"], content=serializer.data["content"])
else:
    #the author id does not exist will cause serializer.is_valid=Flase
```

PS

I knew PrimaryKeyRelatedField in ModelSerializer，but I can't use ModelSerializer here， the model structures are complex, the above are just examples。

My first thought is to write a customer field.

Comment: Did you switch `People` to `Author` half way through this post?

Comment: Do you just want to check that for any given `Blog` there is an `Author/People` value in the DB before you create the `Blog`?

Comment: @isomarcte yes, i want to do that in serializer and then serializer gives me a model instance.It can reduce repetitive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ForeignKeyField(WritableField):

    def __init__(self, model_name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ForeignKeyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.model_instance = None

    def from_native(self, pk):
        if not isinstance(pk, int):
            raise ValidationError("pk must be int")
        try:
            self.model_instance = self.model_name.objects.get(pk=pk)
            return self.model_instance
        except self.model_name.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('object does not exist')

    def to_native(self, obj):
        return self.model_instance
```

I hacked it, but I don't konw why it works.

**Usage:**
there is a little difference

```
class t_serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    author = ForeignKeyField(Author)

@api_view(["POST"])
def func(request):
    serializer = t_serializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        print isinstance(serializer.data["author"], Author)
        #print True
    else:
        print serializer.errors
```

Comment: Are you modifying the Django source?

Comment: @isomarcte  No, I wrote ForeignKeyField.

Comment: I see. I thought there was a class by that name in the Django source.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what you want is custom validation code.

For this particular instance, you could write the following.

```
class CreateBlogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    author = serializers.ForeignKeyField(Author)
    content = serializers.TextField()

    def validate_author(self, attrs, source):
        """
        Verify that the author exists.
        """
        author = attrs[source]
        if Author.objects.filter(pk=author).exists():
            return attrs
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Specified Author does not exist!")
```

Now when you call `serializer.is_valid()` this check will occur.

So you can then do this elsewhere in your code,

```
if serializer.is_valid():
     blog = Blog.objects.create(author=serializer.data["author"], content=serializer.data["content"])
```

And be sure that if the given `blog` is created, there is a corresponding `Author` already in the DB.

## Detailed Explanation

So Django Rest Framework provides a method of adding custom validation to serializers. This can be done with by providing methods of the following format in the serializer class `validate_<field name>`. These methods will set the `source` value to name of the given field, in our example `author`, which can then be used with the `attrs` variable to get the current value of the field (`attrs` contains all the values passed into the serializer).

These validation methods are each called with then `serializer.is_valid()` method is called. They are supposed to just return `attrs` if the given test passes, and raise a `ValidationError` otherwise.

They can get somewhat complex, so it is probably best if you read the full documentation here, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#validation

Comment: thanks, but I want to do validation in serializer, see the answer below.

Comment: @virusdefender Validation is done in the serializer in my answer. These validation methods are *methods on the serializer class*.